# How to use Netlify CMS with Novela theme?

Tags: themes, gatsby, netlify-cms, jamstack

I want to use Netlify CMS with Novela theme. The structure is here:
 https://github.com/narative/gatsby-theme-novela#step-2-folder-structure

In particular, there are subfolders to "posts", and images are stored in individual folders (and not in a big folder).

This created issues in Summer 2019:
here: https://github.com/narative/gatsby-theme-novela/issues/151
here: https://github.com/narative/gatsby-theme-novela/pull/56

Comment: can you add more details about the step you got stuck?

Comment: I got the same problem as here: https://github.com/narative/gatsby-theme-novela/pull/56